# express status code not updating, getting json message update

Tags: node.js, express

I am not getting status message as `500` eventhough I set. always getting status message as `200`. how to set the status as 500?

here is my code : `"express": "4.17.2",`

```
    router.post('/register', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
      const { password, email } = req.body;
      try {
        const isUserExist = await UserModel.findOne({ email: email });
        if (isUserExist) {
          //status not set.
          return res.json({ message: 'User already exist', success: false }).status(500);
        }
        const hashPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10);
        req.body.password = hashPassword;
        const newUser = new UserModel(req.body);
        await newUser.save();
        res.json({ message: 'user created successfully', success: true });
      } catch (error) {
        res.sendStatus(500).json({ message: 'Error creating user', success: false });
      }
    });
```

react axios:

when i use:

`return res.status(500).json({ message: 'User already exist', success: false });` getting `something went wrong`

```
export const registerUser = createAsyncThunk('post/user', async (user: RegisterFormProps) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(environment.BASE_URL + '/user/register', user);
    console.log('suc', response.data.success);
    if (response.data.success) {
      toast.success(response.data.message);
    } else {
      toast.error(response.data.message);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    const err = error as AxiosError;
    console.log('err', err);
    toast.error('something went wrong');
  }
});
```

Comment: `res.sendStatus(500)` should be `res.status(500)`. I suggest you read the documentation for the methods you're using ~ https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendStatus

Comment: if I update like : ` if (isUserExist) {
      return res.json({ message: 'User already exist', success: false }).sendStatus(500);
    }` getting an error as `Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Comment: The order should be `res.status(500).json(...)`

Comment: Axios throws to the `catch` block if the response is not successful. Isn't this working as expected?

Comment: @Phil when the user exist why it goes to `catch` block instead to get my error? (500)

Comment: I literally just told you why. A 500 status is **not** successful. See https://github.com/axios/axios/#handling-errors

Comment: so, status 500 is not applicable here then? it should be 200?

Comment: [409 Conflict](https://http.cat/409) would be a better choice IMO but it will still go to your `catch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `res.status` instead of `res.sendStatus` in your code.

`res.status(statusCode)` just sets the status on the response.
whereas `res.sendStatus(statusCode)` sends the response after setting the status.

for example:

res.sendStatus(500); // equivalent to res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error')

on the client side try using `error.response.data` in your catch block

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
router.post('/register', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
      const { password, email } = req.body;
      try {
        const isUserExist = await UserModel.findOne({ email: email });
        if (isUserExist) {
          //status not set.
          return res.status(500).json({ message: 'User already exist', success: false });
        }
        const hashPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 10);
        req.body.password = hashPassword;
        const newUser = new UserModel(req.body);
        await newUser.save();
        res.status(201).json({ message: 'user created successfully', success: true });
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error creating user', success: false });
      }
    });
```

Comment: it throws error as `something went wrong` from my axios. let me post my axios part

Comment: @CircuitPlanet - can you check my update?